# Xamarin.Forms: Customize action sheet (ContentDialog) on UWP

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm displaying an action sheet with [`await DisplayActionSheet()`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Page.DisplayActionSheet/p/System.String/System.String/System.String/System.String[]/#Xamarin.Forms.Page.DisplayActionSheet_Method). The action sheet consists of a `ListView` embedded into a `ContentDialog` (see [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/0cc2fd2b6742a29fedc03de942801cc14ff6b499/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT/Platform.cs)). Now I want to customize the `PrimaryButton`, `SecondaryButton` and so on. It seems that is [not so easy possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28555396/426227).

If I use the following styles in the `App.xaml` of the UWP project, I can customize the button, but I also overwrite the font color of the items in the `ListView`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush" Color="White" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush" Color="Blue" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

It is also not possible to use implicit styles defined in the `App.xaml` of the XF portable project, because they don't get applied:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Blue" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Rob has already given the answer and the workaround, it's not customizable, but you can unset the buttons and add your own buttons and customize them.

Comment: I got that. The question however is, how can I customize that in Xamarin.Forms. I'm not calling the `ContentDialog` directly. Instead, I call `await DisplayActionSheet()` and the framework does the rest. I think a custom renderer wouldn't help here. What I only can imagine is that you write your own action sheet.